# How to detect sentence boundaries with OpenNLP and stringi?

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, opennlp, stringi

I want to break next `string` into sentences:

```
library(NLP) # NLP_0.1-7  
string <- as.String("Mr. Brown comes. He says hello. i give him coffee.")
```

I want to demonstrate two different ways. One comes from package `openNLP`:

```
library(openNLP) # openNLP_0.2-5  

sentence_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(language = "en")  
boundaries_sentences<-annotate(string, sentence_token_annotator)  
string[boundaries_sentences]  

[1] "Mr. Brown comes."   "He says hello."     "i give him coffee."
```

And second comes from package `stringi`:

```
library(stringi) # stringi_0.5-5  

stri_split_boundaries( string , opts_brkiter=stri_opts_brkiter('sentence'))

[[1]]  
 [1] "Mr. "                              "Brown comes. "                    
 [3] "He says hello. i give him coffee."
```

After this second way I need to prepare sentences to remove extra spaces or break a new string into sentences again. Can I adjust stringi function to improve result's quality?

When it is about a big data, `openNLP` is (very much) slower then `stringi`.
Is there a way to combine `stringi` (->fast) and `openNLP` (->quality)?

Comment: if you don't get an answer here, you may have luck on the [corpus linguistics with R forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/corpling-with-r)

Comment: I opened this as an issue on **stringi**'s HitHub page as well: https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/issues/184

Comment: OpenNLP and stringi differ from each other  about how to detect sentence boundaries. stringi seems work with a set of rules. And openNLP works with a model from a learning proces. But I still don't see where bottle neck lies...

Answer (score 9):

Text boundary (in this case, sentence boundary) analysis in ICU (and thus in stringi) is governed by the rules described in Unicode [UAX29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Sentence_Boundaries), see also [ICU Users Guide on the topic](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis). We read:

> [The Unicode rules] cannot detect cases such as “...Mr. Jones...”; more sophisticated tailoring would be required to detect such cases.

In other words, this cannot be done without a custom dictionary of non-stop words, which in fact is implemented in `openNLP`. A few possible scenarios to incorporate stringi for performing this task would therefore include:

1. Use `stri_split_boundaries` and then write a function deciding on which incorrectly split tokens should be joined.
2. Manually input non-breaking spaces into the text (possibly after dots following *etc.*, *Mr.*, *i.e.* and so on (note that this in fact is required when preparing documents in LaTeX -- otherwise you get too huge spaces between words).
3. Incorporate a custom non-stop word list into a regex and apply the `stri_split_regex`.

and so on.

Comment: This inspired a better solution below that you may be able to incorporate into **stringi** at some point.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a viable regex solution:

```
string <- "Mr. Brown comes. He says hello. i give him coffee."
stringi::stri_split_regex(string, "(?<!\\w\\.\\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\\.)(?<=\\.|\\?|\\!)\\s")

## [[1]]
## [1] "Mr. Brown comes."   "He says hello."     "i give him coffee."
```

Performs less well on:

```
string <- "Mr. Brown comes! He says hello. i give him coffee.  i will got at 5 p. m. eastern time.  Or somewhere in between"
```